# Pull JSON data and find value based on cell value in sheets using Google Script

Tags: json, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to build an API to pull prices from KuCoin and dump them into my sheets file to do some calculations. Yet, I cant find a way to easily pull data from the API and only print data into a cell depending on the equation. Trying to make something like getKucoinPrice(BTC-USDT) and have it print a live value of BTC-USDT based of the kucoin exchange. I found [this](https://trade.kucoin.com/_api/kucoin-web-front/margin/mark-prices/last-records?c=f4df8bab49d0493db832063aa39d2320&lang=en_US) API, and was trying to use [this](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs) to parse the jSON but cant filter for a request. Please help me I'm so so so very lost!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I found this API, and was trying to use this to parse the jSON but cant filter for a request.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Looking at “found this API” it looks like a typical JSON file and simply using JSON.parse will create an object that can be transverse.  What you really need is documentation of the API otherwise you’re just guessing about the object tree

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but it might get us there.

Using the JSON file from your link https://trade.kucoin.com/_api/kucoin-web-front/margin/mark-prices/last-records?c=f4df8bab49d0493db832063aa39d2320&lang=en_US and using the following code:

```
var o = JSON.parse(text);
Object.entries(o).map(itemArray => { 
 console.log("key=", itemArray[0], "value=", itemArray[1])
});
```

A portion of the object tree is shown below.  These are object properties not just text.  What are you trying to get from this data?

```
key= data value= [ { currency: 'BTC', symbol: 'BTC-BTC', value: '1' },
  { currency: 'NANO', symbol: 'NANO-BTC', value: '0.00005730837' },
  { currency: 'POND',
    symbol: 'POND-BTC',
    value: '0.00000114801525' },
  { currency: 'REN', symbol: 'REN-BTC', value: '0.000008504251' },
  { currency: 'ROSE',
    symbol: 'ROSE-BTC',
    value: '0.0000088381125' },
  { currency: 'OXT', symbol: 'OXT-BTC', value: '0.000006259341' },
  { currency: 'SAND', symbol: 'SAND-BTC', value: '0.000098217504' },
  { currency: 'LINK', symbol: 'LINK-BTC', value: '0.0004299183' },
  { currency: 'NEO', symbol: 'NEO-BTC', value: '0.00054364212' },
  { currency: 'UNI', symbol: 'UNI-BTC', value: '0.000285879345' },
  { currency: 'AR', symbol: 'AR-BTC', value: '0.000952363405' },
  { currency: 'NKN', symbol: 'NKN-BTC', value: '0.0000054723228' },
  { currency: 'TRX', symbol: 'TRX-BTC', value: '0.00000159' },
  { currency: 'SHIB',
    symbol: 'SHIB-BTC',
    value: '0.000000000558931' },
  { currency: 'XLM', symbol: 'XLM-BTC', value: '0.00000522' },
  { currency: 'KSM', symbol: 'KSM-BTC', value: '0.004409967555' },
  { currency: 'NEAR',
```

The following code displays some of the currency names:

```
var o = JSON.parse(text);
console.log("num = "+o.data.length)
for( var i=0; i<o.data.length; i++ ) {
  console.log("i = "+i+" symbol = "+o.data[i].symbol);
}
```

Which will produce:

```
8:06:39 PM  Info    num = 162
8:06:39 PM  Info    i = 0 symbol = BTC-BTC
8:06:39 PM  Info    i = 1 symbol = NANO-BTC
8:06:39 PM  Info    i = 2 symbol = POND-BTC
8:06:39 PM  Info    i = 3 symbol = REN-BTC
8:06:39 PM  Info    i = 4 symbol = ROSE-BTC
8:06:39 PM  Info    i = 5 symbol = OXT-BTC
.
.
.
8:06:39 PM  Info    i = 159 symbol = DEXE-BTC
8:06:39 PM  Info    i = 160 symbol = DEGO-BTC
8:06:39 PM  Info    i = 161 symbol = ERN-BTC
```